# CSS - Displaying boxes on separate rows

Tags: css

Im trying to display my posts on serperate rows, but they keep overflowing the bounds of the container. I tried setting the width of of parent to a minimum, but it still overflows. heres a link to my blog site

www.darealistmedia.com

There you can see my problem. And heres the my CSS file. "Main" is the container im trying to keep them in.

```css
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
h1 {
    font:bold 20px Tahoma;
}
h2 {
    font:bold 14px Tahoma;
}
header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup {
    display:block;
}
body {
    width:100%;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
}
.holder {
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:15px 0;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
}
header {
    background:yellow;
    border:3px solid black;
    padding:auto;
    /*20*/
}
.navigation {
    border:3px solid black;
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
.navigation div {
    display:inline-block;
}
.new_div {
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
}
.main {
    text-align:center;
    border:4px solid orange;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    margin:20px;
    padding:20px;
}
.right-sidebar {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:220px;
    margin:20px;
    margin: background:#66cccc;
}
footer {
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    border-top:2px solic green;
}
/*Post Styles*/
.postSection {
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    width:800px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.postWrapper {
    border:2px solid red;
    padding:5px;
    margin:11px;
    width:270px;
    height:270px;
}
.postTitle {
    background-color:#303030;
    font-size:28px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Trajan Pro;
    color:white;
    padding:5px;
}
.postContent {
    background:#c7c7c7;
}
.postTabs {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#202020;
    float:left;
    color:white;
    padding:5px;
}
.day {
    font-size:30px;
}
.linkList {
    float:right;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not dump a whole page of CSS. Identify the issue and come up with a short example that can reproduce the problem. And do not just link to your website. Please read: [Something in my project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: My apologies sir, I'm jus eager to get it working

Answer (score 0):

This behaves exactly as it is supposed to. You told the postWrapper to have a height of 270px, and it does, even if the content is larger. You could use `overflow: hidden;` to hide the extra content, but this will cut off your content mid-sentence. Possibly better to replace `height: 270px;` with `min-height: 270px;`:

```
.postWrapper {
    border:2px solid red;
    padding:5px;
    margin:11px;
    width:270px;
    min-height:270px;
}
```

Comment: But by changing the size of the wrapper, would it effect how it flows within the main div?

Comment: And also, that isnt really the issue, I'm focusing more on the posts being displayed on seperate rows rather thenn overflowing the main div bounds with the orange border

Comment: Do you have an idea of how I can fix it? I apologize for the lack of specifics I'm just trying to get it working